# Hibernate selecting strings and not objects

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to the Hibernate world, and I have a problem that I couldn't solve myself. And please be nice.

**What I have :**

- Netbeans IDE 8.0.2
- Mysql database (easyPHP) with some tables

**What I want :**

- Select categories (table) which has 3 records with **id**,**name**, and **description** and show them (**name** and **description**) in jsp using EL.

**My Category Class:**

```
public class Category  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private String description;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Category(String name, String description) {
       this.name = name;
       this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**My getCategories method :**

```
            public static List getAllCategories(){
               Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
               Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
               List results = session.createCriteria(Category.class, "category")
               .list();
               tx.commit();
               return results; 
            }
```

**My Controller:**

```
                    List categories = CategoriesManagement.getAllCategories();
                    map.addAttribute("categories", categories);
```

**My view (jsp):**

```
<c:forEach var="cat" items="${categories} ">
   ${cat.name}
</c:forEach>
```

I'm getting nothing.

And when I show **${cat.class}** it says :

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
```

And when I show **${cat}** it says :

```
com.company.Category@7136faa
com.company.Category@25636faa
com.company.Category@83baeaa
```

**Update :**

When I redefine toString() method in Category like this :

```
public toString(){
   return "foo";
}
```

I get :

```
[foo
foo
foo]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus, I updated the post with the output and my Category class.

Comment: You can print values as, ${cat.name} and ${cat.description}. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes Prerak but I get nothing...

Comment: I'd say print out the contents of your list before returning it from the controller

Comment: As I updated my answer, hibernate uses toString method and returns the returned values. So I'm getting now three "foo" strings in my list. What it should do is select the 3 object of type Category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's wierd and after 9 hours I found that the space in
`<c:forEach var="cat" items="${categories} ">` was the error,
I should do as :
`<c:forEach var="cat" items="${categories}">`

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `<c:out value="${cat.name}" />`